Existence of a $2\times 2$ real matrix.

Question:-Let $u_1,u_2,w_1$ and $w_2$ be nonzero elements in $\mathbb{R^2}$.Then there exists a $2\times 2$ real matrix $A$ s.t. $Au_1=u_2$ and $Aw_1=w_2$.Prove or disprove the above statement.

Some informations that I have been able to gather are:
1).Since dimension of $\mathbb{R^2}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is 2 hence given vectors are linearly dependent.
2).$u_2$ and $w_2$ are in the range space of $A$.
But I can not connect them for the solution.Kindly someone help me.

do you mean $v_1$ or $u_1$.

What if $w_1$ is the zero vector and $w_2$ is not?

@AngaeMT I have edited my post.Thank you for pointing out the mistake.

@J.W.Tanner In that case the statement will be false.

@J.W.Tanner please see my recent edit.thank you

Linear transformations are very rigid, in the sense that they are completely determined by where they send basis vectors. If $u_1$ and $w_1$ are linearly independent, then the claim will be true because $u_1$ and $w_1$ form a basis of $\mathbb R^2$.
But suppose that $u_1$ and $w_1$ are linearly dependent. In this particular case, this means that $u_1$ and $w_1$ are scalar multiples of each other. Any linear transformation represented by a matrix $A$ will map both $u_1$ and $w_1$ to some line through the origin (in other words, $Au_1$ and $Aw_1$ will also be scalar multiples of each other). You can find a counterexample to the statement by choosing a vector $w_2$ which does lie along this line.

One issue is that you can have $u_1 = w_1$ but $u_2 \neq w_2$ by definition, in which case no such $A$ exists for obvious reasons.
In general if one of $u_1$, $w_1$ is a multiple of the other, you can make $u_2$ and $w_2$ not be multiples of each other so that no such $A$ exists as matrix multiplication is a linear map.
However, if $u_1$ and $w_1$ are linearly independent, we can create our matrix $A$ as
$$ A = [u_2, w_2]\cdot [u_1, w_1]^{-1}$$
where we treat $u_1, u_2, w_1, w_2$ as column vectors to make $2\times 2$ matrices. This construction works since multiplying by $[u_1, w_1]^{-1}$ sends $u_1$ and $w_1$ to the standard basis vectors, and $[u_2, w_2]$ sends these basis vectors to the appropriate output.
